# Regex for a word that can't be preceded by another word but must be preceded by certain characters

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I want to match occurrences of a word in my string. The word cannot be preceded by the word "per", but must be preceded by a word boundary or numbers.  So for example if my word to match were "pie", this would match

```
"123pie"
"abc pie"
"d-pie"
```

but this would not

```
"per pie"
"mpie"
```

I was able to figure out how to write a regex that specifies my word cannot be preceded by the word "per" ...

```
regex = /(?<!per\s)#{Regexp.escape(word)}(\s|$)/i
```

I don't know how to incorporate the other conditions in there.  How can I do that?

Comment: Try [`/(?<!per\s)(?<=\b|\d)#{Regexp.escape(word)}(?!\S)/i`](http://rubular.com/r/O9WwgXpDT4)

Comment: Which other conditions?

Comment: `regex = /(?<!per\s|\p{L})#{Regexp.escape(word)}(?!\S)/i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got part of it with the negative lookbehind, just add a positive lookbehind for a word break or digit and that should do it:

```
/(?<!per\s)(?<=\b|\d)#{Regexp.escape(word)}/i
```

Example:

```
> strs
[
  [0] "123pie",
  [1] "abc pie",
  [2] "abc Pie",
  [3] "d-pie",
  [4] "per pie",
  [5] "mpie",
  [6] "perpie"
]

> word = "pie"

> regex = /(?<!per\s)(?<=\b|\d)#{Regexp.escape(word)}/i

> strs.select {|str| str =~ regex }
[
  [0] "123pie",
  [1] "abc pie",
  [2] "abc Pie",
  [3] "d-pie"
]
```

See: http://rubular.com/r/slD3Uz9iw9 for an interactive example.

And: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors